# Plot a curve having no equation

Tags: graphing-functions

I don't have the equation of the curve. The curve has a maxima and a minima as the following fig. How to plot such smooth graph using tex. Please suggest. Is it possible to suggest an equation of the curve have the same structure?
How to get y such that y passing through (8,0) and (0,5) has a mimima at suppose (2, 4) and maxima at (6, 8)

[image]

Edit: [image]

Curve of y=-(x+1)(x-2)(x-3)

Comment: Cubics look like that...you should be able to fit a cubic to the roots or the critical points.

Comment: Please suggest an equation,,,  (x + 1)*(x -2)*(x - 3) is not of the above shape..

Comment: Clearly the lead coefficient has to be negative.  Just multiply your form by $-1$.  Of course, if you have points (like the critical points) that you want to fit, you'll have to adjust the coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that the lead coefficient has to be negative... But getting a shape like this is very difficult.. Is there any option to plot instead?

Comment: Please be specific.  The function you suggested, multiplied by $-1$, has the shape you sketched.  Are there specific points you want it to go through?  Your question is very vague.  The specific cubic you wrote down goes through $(0, -6)$ so if you want it to go through $(0,8)$ just add $14$.  Beyond that...well, we can't guess what requirements you have.

Comment: Do you know the coordinates of the two extrema? This will be very helpful information.

Comment: Please edit your post to include all the details you wanted, and to include your own efforts.  And...did you mean $(8,0)$?  Your picture shows $(0,8)$.  The graph you drew clearly does not pass through $(0,3)$.

Comment: @lulu I have edited with a detailed description

Comment: You have been given a great deal of information, please try to work on this yourself.  Note that you probably can't fit a cubic with exactly those properties, but you can come close.  The unique cubic passing through those four points is $-\frac {13 x^3}{96} + \frac {4 x^2}3 - \frac {21 x}8 + 5$ but the critical points of that are slightly off the desired values.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=interpolating+polynomial+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InterpolatingPolynomialCalculator%22%2C+%22data2%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B0%2C5%7D%2C%7B2%2C4%7D%2C%7B6%2C8%7D%2C%7B8%2C0%7D%7D%22) has an interpolating polynomial calculator, which is how I found the cubic I wrote, but you can use it to try to better fit the curve you want (you'll need degree $>3$ to get much better).

Comment: Excellent help... I need exactly this ..Thanks

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_interpolation

Answer (score 1):

Of course to plot something it must ... *be* something.  That is to say, in this case, it must be *some* function.

But given the constraints, you can pick anything you want, as long as it meets the constraints.  Judging from the picture, the main constraints that I see represented are:

- It goes to infinity as $x\to-\infty$ and it goes to $-\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.
- It has a local minimum and maximum.
- It is "smooth" (continuous derivatives of all orders, let's say).

So $-x(x-1)(x+1)$ should suffice, which you can easily plot in almost any mathematical plotting software.

If the graph is supposed to fit in some kind of a box with the origin in the lower-left corner as it seems it might be in the picture, then you can shift and scale the graph until it fits.  To scale it, use

$$ -rx(x-1)(x+1) $$

for any $r$ you like, to shrink or expand it vertically.  To shrink or expand horizontally

$$-r(sx)(sx-1)(sx+1)$$

To translate this up and right by the vector $\langle h,k\rangle$, use

$$-r(s[x-h])(s[x-h]-1)(s[x-h]+1) + k$$

So you can play with the parameters $r,s,h,k$ until it fits where you want it.